# Typeform answers integration in server database

Tags: javascript, api, webhooks, typeform

I am using webhooks of typeform to get the answers. Now I want to directly store the answers in my database.
For example, if a user is entering his/her name, then the answer should directly be stored in user model. To make it work i need some information from the question that it is user's name.
Is there any way of adding a hidden tag(name, age, gender) to identify the questions. I can not hard code the question ids, as i have a lot of forms with different types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store response in database table then you have to make it hard codded or create table while getting response.
i.e read question array from response and create table accordingly and store response in newly created table. On next time check if there is table is created or not, if yes then store value else create new table.

Here is my sample code to read response dynamically:

```
function renderData(data) {
var header = '', rows = '';
var questions = data.questions;
var responses = data.responses;
for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
    header += '<th>' + questions[j].question + '</th>';
}
for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    rows += "<tr>"
    for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
        if (responses[i].answers[questions[j].id] == undefined) {
            rows += '<td> - </td>'
        } else {
            rows += '<td>' + responses[i].answers[questions[j].id] + '</td>';
        }
    }
    rows += "</tr>"
}
$('table').append(
        '<table>' + '<thead>' + header + '</thead>' + '<tbody>' + rows
                + '</tbody>' + '</table>');
};
```

Above function get `data` as response from typeform API and create table of your answer.
I hop it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest matching field titles with a with a regex. Since the field titles are in sentences, it's useful to match them in a specific order, and take fields that have already been matched out of the running. More specific fields should be matched first. This is similar to the cucumber testing tool which uses plain english.

Here's some code that I haven't tried running yet, to give an idea of what I'm getting at:

```js
class TypeformReader() {
    constructor(data) {
        this.fields = data.form_response.definition.fields;
        this.answers = data.form_response.answers;
        this.read = [];
    }

    getAnswer(pattern, markRead = false, ignoreRead = true) {
        for (let field of this.fields) {
            if (ignoreRead && this.read.includes(field.id)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (pattern.test(field.title)) {
                for (let answer of this.answers) {
                    if (answer.field.id == field.id)
                        if (markRead) {
                            this.read.push(field.id);
                        }
                        return answer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to use this class. If you have a typeform for a dog yoga class that says "What's your name?" and "What's the name of your dog?" you'd want to match the longer one first (also included is "What's your email?" which is an email field and has the answer in the `email` key of the answer rather than `text`).

```js
const reader = new TypeformReader(req.data);
const dogName = reader.getAnswer(/\bname\b.*\bdog\b/).text;
const name = reader.getAnswer(/\bname\b/).text;
const email = reader.getAnswer(/\bemail\b').email;
```